# Dymola getExperiment() access

Tags: function, built-in, modelica, dymola

Does anyone know how to access specific outputs of the Dymola built-in function getExperiment();?
Unfortunately it only returns the Real scalar StartTime.
The function seems to be defined as follows:

```
function getExperiment "Get current experiment setting"
  output  Real StartTime  := 0.0 "Start of simulation";
  output  Real StopTime  := 1.0 "End of simulation";
  output  Integer NumberOfIntervals  := 0 "Number of output points";
  output  Real OutputInterval  := 0.0 "Distance between output points";
  output  String Algorithm  := "" "Integration method";
  output  Real Tolerance  := 0.0001 "Tolerance of integration";
  output  Real FixedStepSize  := 0.0 "Fixed step size for Euler";
end getExperiment;
```

My test model is:

```
model GetExpTest
  Real staTime;
  Real outInterval;
equation 
  (staTime,outInterval)=receiveInfo();
end GetExpTest;code here
```

With the function:

```
function receiveInfo
  output Real startT;
  output Real outputInterv;
algorithm 
  (startT,,,outputInterv,,,):=getExperiment();
end receiveInfo;
```

And the error message I get is:

Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++).

dsmodel.c
dsmodel.c(32) : error C2079: 'dummy_mult_' uses undefined struct 'getExperiment_struct'
dsmodel.c(32) : warning C4013: 'getExperiment' undefined; assuming extern returning int
dsmodel.c(33) : error C2224: left of '.StartTime0_0_0member' must have struct/union type
dsmodel.c(34) : error C2224: left of '.OutputInterval0_0_0member' must have struct/union type

Error generating Dymosim.

Thank you in Advance for help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you include the code you are currently using with `getExperiment()`?

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my post and added the test model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I do: `getExperiment()`, the following is returned:

```
= 0.0, 1.0, 500, 0.0, "dassl", 0.0001, 0.0
```

So you can access the values using a regular assignment taking multiple outputs. For example:

```
(StartTime,,NumberOfIntervals) := getExperiment()
```

Which returns:

```
Declaring variable: Real StartTime ;
Declaring variable: Integer NumberOfIntervals ;
StartTime
 = 0.0
NumberOfIntervals
 = 500
```

Comment: This works in the Commands line in the Simulation tab, right. But I want to use the function to read out e.g. the interval length during the simulation (or at least during initialization phase). E.g.:
`function receiveInfo
  output Real startT;
  output Real outputInterv;
algorithm 
  (startT,,,outputInterv,,,):=getExperiment();
end receiveInfo;`

I only get a dsmodel.c error messages.

Comment: I suspect that is because it is a scripting function in Dymola. OpenModelica (which I use) is the same - many of the scripting functions are not available for simulations to access. And indeed getExperiment is not defined in the Modelica specification, so one cannot assume that it would work from a model.